# Can't create an Array of Functions

Tags: swift

I tried making an array of functions and Xcode did not let me. 
This is the error I get:

> Value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> (ViewController)' has no member 'firstFunc'

Essentially I need to know how array of functions are made in order to randomly call them later.

```
let randomFunc = [self.firstFunc(),self.secondFunc(),self.thirdFunc()]

func firstFunc(){
}

func secondFunc(){
}

func thirdFunc(){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to only give the name of the function, currently you are calling the functions,

And if you want to use `self` as well you can do something like this: (you need to make this property `lazy var` to use `self`)

```
class foo {
        lazy var randomFunc = [self.firstFunc,self.secondFunc,self.thirdFunc]
        func firstFunc(){

                print(123)
        }

        func secondFunc(){


        }

        func thirdFunc(){


        }
}
```

Usage:

```
let f = foo()
f.randomFunc[0]()  // prints 123
```

Comment: Hey thanks that worked, it let me create the array but now I don't know how to call it.

Comment: @Alex Glad , I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
lazy var array = [self.fun1,self.fun2,self.fun3]
```

**Functions:**

```
func fun1() {
    print("func1")
}
func fun2() {
    print("func2")

}
func fun3() {
    print("func3")

}
```

**Usage:**

```
self.array[0]()
```

**Prints:**

```
func1
```